# Dynamic Links when sent through email have url defence

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm facing an issue with Firebase dynamic links on iOS . When I send the link via an gmail (HTML hyperlink) , the email gets appended by a urldefence.proofpoint domain to protect the URL most likely . But this causes an issue in the way universal links work . Proofpoint redirects me to the original url after validating the url eventually , but Safari does not open the app at this time . It tries to go to the fallback url . Anyone have any ideas .?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer . For now , redirects are not supported by Universal Links .

[https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/89845#89845](http://I%20got%20the%20answer%20.%20For%20now%20,%20redirects%20are%20not%20supported%20by%20Universal%20Links%20.%20%20%20https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/89845#89845)